# Merging two Custom Post Types into one

Tags: custom-post-types

I am new to all this so my ignorance may get in the way.

I inherited a WP Blog with Custom Post Types.  There are 4 Custom Post Types, out of which 2, **Books** and **Magazines**, have the same fields: Custom_Post_Type_Name, Author, City, Address, Categories, Tags, Date.

I need to merge these two Custom Post Types into one.  More specifically, I need to merge **Books** into **Magazines** and rename this new merged Custom Post Type to **Publications**.

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can ran a simple query once and remove it from your code, something like this:

```
if (!get_option('updated_my_books')){
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query("UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET post_type = 'publications' WHERE post_type IN('books','magazines')");
    update_option('updated_my_books', true);
}
```

Comment: Hi Bainternet. Thanx for the response.  Will this also remove the links on the Admin Panel...???  Also, now would the new name "Publications" show up in the Control Panel...??